# format-number function behaviour

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using format-number function as below

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(userCSharp:GetNumber(),'#.##')" />
```

before applying format function the value of the GetNumber() function is 2217.99863970

and after applying format number function it's converting "2217.99863970" to  "22180".

Is this behavior as expected.

If yes then I want to convert this "2217.99863970" to  "2218". What function will do the same.

I am using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Are you sure your `GetNumber` function is returning that number? What happens if you just do this? `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(2217.99863970,'#.##')" />`

Comment: I tried.. The value is coming as "22180".

Comment: Is there some subsequent statement that is adding the trailing zero, perhaps? Could you possibly amend your question to show a complete, but minimal, XSLT that fully demonstrates the problem? Thank you!

Comment: No there is no subsequent statement.This function is also  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(2217.99863970,'#.##')" giving me "22180" value.

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using, and how are you actually invoking the transformation?